# CRITICAL Uncaught DivisionByZeroError

Tags: php, wordpress

got a wordpress installation thats been hammering the SQL database for quite some time, so starting to look through it and fix things up.

WooCommerce is doing 96375 entries in 3 minutes 43383 select statements and 136 inserts which in itself is a problem.

However, in the log files its reporting the following :

```
CRITICAL Uncaught DivisionByZeroError: Modulo by zero in....Line:444
```

Checking the referenced file on line 444 i get the following :

```
if($count % $showposts  != 0){
  $no_of_pages++;
}
```

Not 100% sure what is wrong with this line of code, but if someone could shed some light on it, that would be a great help!

Many thanks

Comment: Wait. Is this piece of code from a theme, plugin or WordPress itself?

Comment: Sorry this is from a theme file

Comment: the reason I asked is that if this is from a theme file, the theme is of low quality. there might be other problems with the codes. You'd better find a better theme.

Answer (score 1):

Verify under what conditions $showposts is equal to 0.

You could modify line 444 to:

```
if($showposts && ($count % $showposts  != 0)){
  $no_of_pages++;
}
```